# ObjectAnimator not pausing

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I'm trying to add a `addPauseListener` to my `ObjectAnimator` object, but this doesn't pause the object.This is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

TextView txt;
ObjectAnimator anim;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_message);

    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(txt,"translationY", -200,500);
    anim.setDuration(30000);
    anim.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    anim.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
    anim.start();
    //anim.addPauseListener(pauseListener);

}

    /*Animator.AnimatorPauseListener pauseListener = new Animator.AnimatorPauseListener() {
        public void onAnimationPause(Animator animation) {
               animation.pause() ;
        }
        public void onAnimationResume(Animator animation) {
                animation.start();
         }
    };*/

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventAction = event.getAction();

        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN==eventAction){
            anim.pause();
        }
        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP==eventAction){
            anim.resume();
        }
    return true;
    };
 }
```

Using this method I get an error at:

```
09-11 10:02:39.431  17385-17385/com.example.rs.myapplication E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.animation.ValueAnimator.pause()' on a null object reference
```

How can I get the desired action so that when the device is touched the animation pauses and when untouched animation resumes back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 anim objects. One is local and one global. You never set the global one, you only define the local one in the oncreate method. Hence the null object error.

Change this line:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(txt,"translationY", -200,500);
```

To just this:

```
anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(txt,"translationY", -200,500);
```

Also it is generally bad to start the animation in the oncreate method. I've never personally had a need to do this, but the consensus that I've read says to do it in the onWindowFocusChanged method.

Comment: @Whitney....Thanks for the spot, I had initially made the object `local` and when I made it `global` I had forgotten to remove the creation of the `local` object as well. It works now and thanks also for the heads up about the `onWindowFocusChanged`, I wasn't aware of this as I'm still new to Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
    anim.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE); //so that it's does not pause object.
```

you can set counter to animation like 10, 20, 30 or as you want repeat that object as you want

```
    anim.setRepeatCount(10); // 10 time repeat object after complete that will stop / pause
```

Comment: What if you need the animation to run infinitely?

Comment: @user94628 it seems you have to recreate an anim object each time